# Hide separator if items are hidden in a context menu

Tags: xaml, visibility, separator

I would like to hide the separator in my context menu when all the menuitems are hidden.
If at least one of the two menuitems is visible, the separator must be visible too.

I've tried that:

```
<Separator>
    <Separator.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Separator">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=Visibility, ElementName=Item1}" Value="Collapsed" />
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=Visibility, ElementName=Item2}" Value="Collapsed" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="Separator.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                </MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=Visibility, ElementName=Item1}" Value="Visible" />
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=Visibility, ElementName=Item2}" Value="Visible" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="Separator.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                </MultiDataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Separator.Style>
</Separator>

<MenuItem x:Name="Item1"  Header="Item1" Visibility="{Binding Item1Visibility, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
<MenuItem x:Name="Item2"  Header="Item2" Visibility="{Binding Item2Visibility, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
```

But the separator is always hidden.
What's wrong with my code?